# Always get ObjectMapper failed to serialize response

Tags: ios, swift

Please don't mark as duplicate because I could not found a solution from all question
I am using alamofireObjectMapper
In my app the project is created using api with some parameters like Name, Description, and images are stored in our own storage and URL is stored using API
Whenever i update my project old images should be deleted and new ones should be added
But whenever I send array of prject images it says "FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofireobjectmapper.error Code=2 "ObjectMapper failed to serialize response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=ObjectMapper failed to serialize response."

Code is below:

```
 if isForUpdate {
                
                imageKey = "img_to_add[]"
                parameters["project_id"] = "\(projectDetail?.id ?? -1)"
//                parameters["area_of_exp_id[]"] = areaOfInterestList
//                parameters["location"] = address
                if projectDetail?.project_images?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                    
                    parameters["img_to_delete[]"] = projectDetail?.project_images!
                    print("Parameters are: ",parameters)
                }
                
                addProject(APIUrl.updateProject, parameters, imageKey)
```

Add project function is also used for update project

```
    func addProject(_ apiUrl: String, _ parmas: [String: Any],_ imageKey: String) {
        
        self.loadingIndicator?.startAnimating()

        let dict = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ProfileModal") as? [String: Any]
        let token  = dict?["token"] as! String
        print(apiUrl, parmas)
        
        CommonAPIs.shared().uploadImage(apiUrl: apiUrl, parameters: parmas, token: token, imagesData: ImagesDataArray, imageKey: imageKey) { (response) in
            
            self.loadingIndicator?.stopAnimating()
            
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: response.status ?? false ? AlertConstants.Success : "Request Failed", message: response.status ?? false ? "Data Save Successfully." : AlertConstants.SomeThingWrong, preferredStyle: .alert)

                // Create the actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
                    UIAlertAction in
                self.resetField()
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
                
            }

                // Add the actions
                alertController.addAction(okAction)

                // Present the controller
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            
        } onFailure: { (error) in
            self.loaderIndicator?.stopAnimating()
            self.showAlertWith(title: AlertConstants.Error, message: error?.localizedDescription ?? AlertConstants.SomeThingWrong )
        } onError: { (errorMessage) in
            self.loaderIndicator?.stopAnimating()
            self.showAlertWith(title: AlertConstants.Error, message: errorMessage?.description ?? AlertConstants.SomeThingWrong )
        }
      
    }
```

And Image Upload function

```
    func uploadImage(apiUrl: String, parameters: [String: Any], token: String,imagesData: [UIImage], imageKey: String, onSuccess success: @escaping (_ response: DeleteProjectResponse ) -> Void, onFailure failure: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void, onError message: @escaping (_ mess: String?) -> Void){
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
        ]
        
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            // import image to request
            for imageData in imagesData {
                let imgData = imageData.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4)!
                multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: imageKey, fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                print(multipartFormData)
            }
            print(multipartFormData,parameters)
            
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                print(key,value, type(of: value))
                
                if key == "area_of_exp_id[]" || key == "img_to_delete[]" {
                    
                    let arrData =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
                    multipartFormData.append(arrData, withName: key as String)
                    
                } else {
                    

                    multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
                    }
                
            }
            
            print(parameters)

        }, to: apiUrl, headers: headers,
           encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                
                upload.responseObject{(response:DataResponse<DeleteProjectResponse>)  in
                 
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        success(value)
                    case .failure(let error):
    // Error occurs here
                        failure(error)
                    }
                }
            
            case .failure(let error):
                print(" error",error)
                failure(error)
            }

        })
        
    }
```

This is response model

```
class DeleteProjectResponse : Mappable {
    
    var message : String? = ""
    var status : Bool? = nil
    var error: String? = ""
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        message <- map["message"]
        status <- map["status"]
        error <- map ["error"]
    }
    
}
```

And the response through postman is

```
{
    "message": "Updated succesfully",
    "status": true
}
```

Comment: Consider to drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of `Codable`. At least the error messages are pretty much more meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly got the solution
The problem was

```
 if key == "area_of_exp_id[]" || key == "img_to_delete[]" {
                    
                    let arrData =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
                    multipartFormData.append(arrData, withName: key as String)
                    
                }
```

Just commented this code and worked fine
When this code was uncommented response was NULL and was unable to be mapped.